# Displaying Links in order of opening and closing dates

Tags: php, mysql

I have four links stored in MySQL, with opening & closing dates.

I want to display them by Ascending order of closing dates. But while arranging them they should also be arranged in Ascending order of opening dates.

For Eg:

Link A (Opening: 21/10/17 & Closing 23/10/17)

Link B (Opening: 21/10/17 & Closing 22/10/17)

Link C (Opening: 20/10/17 & Closing 23/10/17)

Link D (Opening: 20/10/17 & Closing 22/10/17)

So the links should be displayed as:

- Link D
- Link B
- Link C
- Link A

`Opening Date = Odate & Closing Date = Cdate`

I tried:

`$stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY Cdate ASC ');` 
but it only arranges in ascending order as per closing dates.

My Table Structure [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjwN.png)

Comment: You should restrucutre  your  table then it may possible

Comment: This would consider only text field

Comment: @Dipakchavda Which MySQL table..?

Comment: @NIKHILAWARI whats current output?

Comment: can you show your table structure with dummy data

Comment: @Dipakchavda https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjwN.png

Comment: Please review does it helpful to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will list by closing date in ascending order as well as Opening date in ascending order respectively.

```
  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY Cdate ASC, Odate ASC');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, https://stackoverflow.com/users/8556809/a-iglesias is also correct but ordered wrong, so I accept your answer thank you.

Comment: Thank you A.Igalesias also very well in this.

Answer (score 0):

The `ORDER BY` allows you to put different columns separated by comma...

```
SELECT * FROM links ORDER BY Cdate,Odate
```

... this will order the result first using `Odate` at a first level and then `Cdate`.

Comment: Thank you for answering, your answer somehow solved my problem, but I need `Cdate` as the first level, I was restricted for accepting answers for 5 minutes, so I couldn't accept your answer as in the meantime https://stackoverflow.com/users/4030664/dipak-chavda answered it more accurately, so he deserved the acceptance. I would definitely upvote your answer if I could. Thanks for taking time for me & helping .